# how to use curl with X-Forwarded-For

Tags: curl

Nginx is located at `6`, and sending request from `17` to nginx using curl, use `X-forwarded-for` for the current `17` host. I expected only one request sent, but with `X-forwarded-for`, curl prints another `Failed connect to 10.180.1.17:80; Connection refused`. It seems curl is using host specified in header as a proxy. **So how to use curl to mock a request with header `X-forwarded-for`**.

```
curl -X POST --location "http://10.180.1.6:10000/api/a" \
>     -H "X-forwarded-for": "10.180.1.17" \
>     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
>     -H "Accept-Sign: "6836757ecfcee0fff8fd8f9b997ef4c2e06742ec429de3234956c2fe2576934"" \
>     -d "{\"a\":74276, \"b\" :1999, \"c\":41717, \"time\":1698746820110,\"d\":39718}"
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>openresty</center>
</body>
</html>
curl: (7) Failed connect to 10.180.1.17:80; Connection refused
```